# SVG text not showing in Edge or IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, svg, microsoft-edge

I am using the code below to put an image in an SVG and some bunch of text directly below it:

```html
<td>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <svg width="200" height="250">
            <defs>
            <clipPath id="circleView">
            <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="#FFFFFF" />            
            </clipPath>
            </defs>
            <image width="100" height="100"  
            xlink:href="http://etc.usf.edu/clipart/63300/63348/63348_clock_500_md.gif" clip-path="url(#circleView)" />
            <text baseline-shift="-130px" text-anchor="bottom" class="smallh2">headertext</text>
            <text baseline-shift="-160px" text-anchor="bottom" class="smallh2" id="objecta"></text>
        </svg>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</td>
```

The first`<text>` shows the heading while the second one calls a html element which has a figure.
The above code works pretty well in Google Chrome but somehow doesn't show the text in IE and Edge.

Comment: Instead of using baseline-shift can you use x and y. It will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace  baseline-shift with y for text. It works in all browsers.

```
<svg width="200" height="250">
                <defs>
                <clipPath id="circleView">
                <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="#FFFFFF" />            
                </clipPath>
                </defs>
                <image width="100" height="100"  
                xlink:href="http://etc.usf.edu/clipart/63300/63348/63348_clock_500_md.gif" clip-path="url(#circleView)" />
                <text y="130" text-anchor="bottom" class="smallh2">headertext</text>
                <text baseline-shift="-160px" text-anchor="bottom" class="smallh2" id="objecta"></text>
            </svg>
```